# How to draw a part of character in canvas using JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to print only a part of a character on canvas using `fillText()` like this:

[image]

I want the part size to be based on a variable (in this case n ~ 0.6).

I don't want to clear a rectangle near the letter so the part of it gets cleared, because there are going to be things drawn underneath it already which I don't want to clear.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: to start with, how would you draw the whole character?

Comment: I would do something like `fillText('A', 30, 100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

**Option one:** [`clip()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip)

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '70px sans serif';
ctx.rect(15, 0, 50, c.height);
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillText('A', 0, 70);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

**Option Two:** `clearRect()`(or `fillRect()` + background color)

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '70px sans serif';
ctx.fillText('A', 0, 70);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 15, c.height);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

*(I know you explicitely said you don't want it, but actually, you can combine it with [`globalCompositeOperations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), so your background is drawn behind the letter.)*

**Option three:** buffer canvas + [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

```js
var buffer = c.cloneNode()
var bctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
bctx.font = '70px sans serif';
bctx.fillText('A', 0, 70);
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(buffer, 15, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height, 15, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

There are of course more options, all of which depending on your actual needs, but these are the main ones and should cover most cases.

And to get the variable size, you can use [`ctx.measureText(yourString).width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) to set the variable needed in each options.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I wasn't aware that `clip()` was a thing, yet it sound to be super useful for drawing complex shapes.